# Ignore "the file is in use by another application or user Normal.dotm"

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

Is there a way to tell Microsoft Word to stop bothering me with prompts about saving `Normal.dotm`?

[image: This file is in use by another application or user. (C:\Users\Ajedi32\AppData...\Normal.dotm]

It's really annoying, and 99.99% of the time I really just don't care. (Seems like pretty poor UX to me.)

Is there a way to tell word to stop bothering me with this?

---

**More details**

As I understand it, `Normal.dotm` is the normal (default) document template. As far as I know, it's an implementation detail of the software, and doesn't concern me as a user. I wasn't even aware I made changes to `Normal.dotm` in the first place, so Word prompting me to save those changes or giving me error messages about being unable to save them is pointless.

Typically this box appears when I open multiple Word documents in rapid succession, then later attempt to close one of them. I suspect it's caused by multiple instances of Word trying to access the document simultaneously.

I've often experienced this annoyance while working with Word, and I seem to recall variations of these prompts appearing in versions of Word dating back all the way to the days of Windows 98 (though I have no way of getting screenshots of those prompts now).

Any solution which causes Word to ignore any problems encountered while saving `Normal.dotm` will work. Assuming it wouldn't cause any serious problems, I'd even be happy with a solution which simply tells Word "don't bother saving Normal.dotm... ever".

Comment: this link describes Words use and triggers for saving the normal template. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291352 the question here though should be, why does the normal.dotm appear to be writelocked by multiple processes. are you in a home or office environment where there are multiple users or remotely shared documents?

Comment: if you delete the normal.dotm from C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates, exit word, and restart it, does the problem continue?

Comment: @FrankThomas Typically this happens when I open multiple word documents on my computer in rapid succession, and later try to close one of them. Fyi I'm running Word 2013, as indicated by this question's tags.

Comment: @FrankThomas It's not a problem that occurs consistently. I suspect it only occurs when two instances of Word try to access that document at the same time.